# Python Discord bot send text instead of emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a simple code that sends an emoji if the message starts with `nails`:

```py
if message.content.startswith('nails'):
    await message.channel.send('<:nails:843081338818789406>')
```

However, the bot only responds `:nails:`, instead of the actual emoji:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that emoji exists within the server?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński yeah i'm sure, we always use it

Comment: And are you sure you copied the name correctly? `\:emoji:` send it and copy the resulting message

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński thank you very much, i copied message id instead of emoji's,it works

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.content.startswith('nails'):
    emoji = bot.get_emoji(843081338818789406)
    await message.channel.send(emoji)
```